# Why can't I insert in database using web service and store produce

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a problem when I try to insert something to my database using my web service and store produce. I have this:

**Client.asmx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebServicesCRUD
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Client
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Client : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public int  InsertDetail(string PersonName,string PersonCity)
        {
                int retRecord = 0;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertDetail", con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("PersonName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = PersonName;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("PersonCity", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = PersonCity;
                        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            con.Open();

                        }
                        retRecord = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                return retRecord;
        }
    }
}
```

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebServicesCRUD
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            localhost.Client objTest = new localhost.Client();
            int ret = objTest.InsertDetail(txtName.Text, txtCity.Text);
            if (ret > 0)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Record Insert Successfully";

            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Error while inserting record";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebServicesCRUD.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtID"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCity"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage">

        </asp:Label>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnInsert" OnClick="btnInsert_Click" Text="Insert" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I fill in all fields, and click in button Insert, give me exception . How can I fix this?

**Description**:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details**:

```
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
> process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
> not set to an instance of an object.    at
> WebServicesCRUD.Client.InsertDetail(String PersonName, String
> PersonCity) in
> E:\Tin\C#\Source\WebServicesCRUD\WebServicesCRUD\Client.asmx.cs:line
> 27    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

**Source Error:**

```
> Line 76:        
> [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/InsertDetail",
> RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/",
> ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/",
> Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal,
> 
> Line 77:         public int InsertDetail(string PersonName, string
> PersonCity) { <br>
Line 78:             object[] results =
> this.Invoke("InsertDetail", new object[] { <br>
Line 79:                   
> PersonName, <br>
 Line 80:                         PersonCity});
> ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
```

Comment: have you checked the values of txtName.Text and txtCity.Text when you pass them to InsertDetails method?

Comment: @apomene: No, I haven't .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 27 would suggest you have missed the connection string from the web services web.config

Comment: How to add miss connection string in my web.config .

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestWebService" connectionString="Data Source=NTLZZ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestWebService;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: Your web service is asking for a connection string named "con". You only have one named "TestWebService"